# How to melt 2 columns at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In Pandas, I have the following data frame:

```
   id1 id2 t1  l1  t2  l2 
0  1   2   a   b   c   d
1  3   4   g   h   i   j
```

I would like to melt two columns at once. That is, the desired output is:

```
   id1 id2 tz  lz  
0  1   2   a   b
1  1   2   c   d
2  3   4   g   h
3  3   4   i   j
```

I know standard melting:

```
d.melt(id_vars=['id1', 'id2'],
       value_vars=['t1', 't2', 'l1', 'l2'])
```

but that stacks all columns

```
   id1  id2 variable value
0    1    2       t1     a
1    3    4       t1     g
2    1    2       t2     c
3    3    4       t2     i
4    1    2       l1     b
5    3    4       l1     h
6    1    2       l2     d
7    3    4       l2     j
```

How could I melt two columns at once? Something like:

```
d.melt(id_vars=['id1', 'id2'],
       value_vars={('t1', 'l1'): 'tz', ('t2', 'l2'): 'lz'})
```

would be great.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is `wide_to_long`

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['t','l'], i=['id1','id2'], j='drop').reset_index(level=[0,1])
Out[52]: 
      id1  id2  t  l
drop                
1       1    2  a  b
2       1    2  c  d
1       3    4  g  h
2       3    4  i  j
```

Comment: Which part makes it select (t1, l1) and (t2, l2), not (t1, t2) and (l1, l2). Does it depend on the order in which the columns appear in the dataframe? if so, can I specify the order? Thanks.

Comment: @hyperio https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html, it is stubnames

Answer (score 5):

You can use `melt` twice here and after that concat them to get desired output:

```
t = d.melt(id_vars=['id1', 'id2'], value_vars=['t1', 't2'], value_name='tz').drop('variable', axis=1)
l = d.melt(id_vars=['id1', 'id2'], value_vars=['l1', 'l2'], value_name='lz').iloc[:, -1:]

df = pd.concat([t, l], axis=1).sort_values('id1')
```

---

Output

```
print(df)
   id1  id2 tz lz
0    1    2  a  b
2    1    2  c  d
1    3    4  g  h
3    3    4  i  j
```